# Multiple queues in AWS with Laravel stop running after sometime

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I have the following setup: Laravel on Elastic Beanstalk and queues per database.
I want to archieve that there are three different queues running in parallel in order to have notifications triggered faster and so on.

Now, my problem is the queues start running as soon as I push to the codepipeline (connected to Elastic Beanstalk), but they stop working after some time until I push again something to the Code Pipeline. Any idea what I need to do to keep them running?

The .env contains:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Then in my queue.php

```
  'connections' => [
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
    'airbnb_sync' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
    'arrange_room_dates' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
]
```

In the job SyncAirbnb I have

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->onQueue('airbnb_sync');
}
```

and then finally I have in .platform/files/supervisor.ini

```
[program:laravel_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:listen --queue=database,default --tries=1
directory=/var/app/current
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-laravel-worker.log
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
startretries=86400


[program:arrange_room_dates]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
command=php artisan queue:listen --queue=arrange_room_dates --tries=1
directory=/var/app/current
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-laravel-worker.log
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
startretries=86400


[program:airbnb_sync]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
command=php artisan queue:listen --queue=airbnb_sync --tries=1
directory=/var/app/current
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor-laravel-worker.log
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
startretries=86400
```

Comment: Honestly, so many things could be going on. I am more inclined that you have something not right on the CI/CD, how are you doing the deploy? Are you restarting the queue? I think it is more related to memory issues or something similar than code or the queue worker itself. Could you run `htop` (or `top`) on the machine that runs the queue workers when it starts not working anymore? Check RAM and CPU usage